# Htaccess URL rewrite with get parameters

Tags: .htaccess, web, url-rewriting, http-status-code-403, getparameter

so I've recently changed my website's file structure a little bit and now need to redirect my old URLs to the new ones.

This is what the old URLs looked like:
`example.com/script?id=1&title=TitleHere`

the script.php is now in a sub-folder with the name "script", so the new URL is:
`example.com/script/1/TitleHere` (This one is already working, but I still need my old urls to redirect to this pattern.)

This is what I tried in my htaccess:
`RewriteRule ^script?id=([0-9]+)&title=(.*) /script/$2-$1 [L,R=301]`

Not sure if this is of importance but I am also using these htaccess settings:

```
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Sadly my attempt didn't bring me any success, it's just throwing a 403 and I think that's because a folder named "script" already exists but I am not sure. Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only, you can not use it to check on query string contents - for that, you need to use a RewriteCond.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, this definitely got me closer to solving my issue!
By using the following code the URL looks a bit weird but it at least works: 

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/script.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)&(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/script/%2-%1? [QSA,R=301,L]` 

Now the issue is, that all my old URLs didn't use .PHP at the end and when I use the above code without the .PHP it seems to redirect the users in a loop, causing it to error. Is there any workaround for this scenario?

 @CBroe

Comment: Remove the first RewriteCond, and make your RewriteRule pattern `^script$` instead. By anchoring it at the end as well with the `$`, it won't allow the URL path to consist of anything more than that, so it won't match your new URL paths of the form `script/...` any more.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it fully working now.
You're a lifesaver. Have a wonderful rest of your day.